# Como colocar texto em um icone?

Tags: html, css

Gostaria de fazer um ícone de carrinho de compra, e colocar um numero dentro dele para ir iterando conforme os produtos que o cliente coloca no carrinho, mas não consegui fazer, um exemplo:
OBs: HTML e CSS, o icone é font-awesome, estou utilizando Bootstrap 4

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

HTML

```
 <div class="content-carrinho d-flex">
     <a href=""><span class="fa fa-shopping-cart" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
 </div>
```

CSS

```
.content-carrinho a {
    padding-right: 40px;
}

.content-carrinho span{
    color: white;
}
```

Comment: Depende do que é este icone, é uma fonte do fontawsome ou do gliph? é um SVG? é uma imagem com `<img>`? Dê detalhes, existem muitas maneiras de se fazer uma mesma coisa, pois vai depender da tecnologia que você usou inicialmente para poder fornecer-lhe uma resposta que vai servir especificamente para o seu caso.

Comment: é um font-awesome, desculpe nao falar na pergunta

Comment: Posta o que já fez até o momento, só a parte HTML do tal icone.

Comment: pronto, a imagem que esta no post é de exemplo

Comment: joão tá usando algum outro framework que eu não saiba? o que significa `d-flex`? Isso pode conflitar com qualquer solução que eu forneça em uma resposta, melhor você ler as recomendações de como formular um exemplo: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, se não as pessoas vão ficar te dados várias soluções a maioria pode falhar por conflitar com algo que tem no teu site e então vamos ficar o dia inteiro até algo funcionar.

Comment: Mesmo não tendo certeza se irá conflitar, eu formulei uma resposta, experimenta https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/237805/3635, se funcionar blz, caso contrário siga o que disse no comentário anterior.

Comment: Obrigado pelo topico de Criação de Exemplos, vou dar uma lida, é meu segundo post aqui, to meio perdido, mas o d-flex é uma propriedade do Bootstrap 4 que deixa o container flex. Obrigado pelo ajuda, vou tentar fazer o exemplo e volto para um feedback

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer o ícone com um *container* para o texto.

Exemplo: https://jsfiddle.net/Ljquqtrv/

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar o seletor de pseudo-elemento chamado `::after` (para navegadores antigos use `:after`) para posicionar um texto acima e usar o atributo do HTML5 chamado `data-` para customizar o valor, então vamos criar um atributo customizado:

```
<span data-qtd="0"
```

Troque o zero pela quantidade que tiver no carrinho e no `::after` use `content: attr()` para pegar o valor do atributo:

```
content: attr(data-qtd);
```

deve ficar assim:

```css
.content-carrinho a {
    padding-right: 40px;
}

.content-carrinho span {
    color: #0c0c0c;
    font-size: 42px; /* ajuste o tamanho do ICONE aqui*/
    position: relative; /* é necessário para enquadrar o ::after */
}

.fa-shopping-cart::after {
    font-size: 24px; /* ajuste o tamanho do texto aqui */
    top: 10px; /* ajusta no centro e vertical */
    content: attr(data-qtd); /*pega o valor do atributo */

    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div class="content-carrinho d-flex">
    <a href="">
       <span data-qtd="0" class="fa fa-shopping-cart" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    </a>
</div>
```